# Integrate Contact Form 7 with ZOHO CRM to capture leads

Tags: wordpress

I have a "Contact form 7" form
which need to be linked to ZOHO CRM to capture leads.

I need a solution so that when a form is submitted the values are recorded in CRM too.

I need to implement this in 6 different forms in Contact form 7 Plugin

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an exact answer but it may point you in the right direction. 
You can run JavaScript after a successful form submission - http://contactform7.com/redirecting-to-another-url-after-submissions/ as well as get variables from your form e.g.

```
on_sent_ok: "var email = document.getElementById('email').value;location = 'http://example.com/thank-you/?email='+email";
```

This needs to be added under the "Additional Settings" tab text area on your contact form 7 form.

Then on your thank you page you can run your ZOHO api connection script.

```
if(isset($_GET['email'])) { #do ZOHO stuff with $_GET['email'] variable}
```

Otherwise in your "on_sent_ok" JavaScript section you can add any JavaScript integration that ZOHO might have.